# Need to convert some HQ PNG images with transparent parts into usable bitmaps

Tags: bitmap, devexpress, png, transparency, delphi-7

I'm using an extension known as DevExpress for Delphi 7. This has a Windows 7 style ribbon control. The control stores big images and small images in respective lists.

So far, our software has had these lists populated in the exe itself. Now, to reduce the size, we are trying to fill them via code. This is tricky because:

1. The lists only accept bitmaps.
2. I believe transparency is lost when
   converted to Bitmaps.

So below is the code I've been trying to use that will either:

Succesfully add our images, but leave white instead of transparent around them

OR

Add no images at all.

```
begin
  FindAllFiles(RbnImgPath + 'v' + IntToStr(vNo) + '\' + RbnImgFolder+'\*.bmp', faAnyFile, RbnImgList);
  for i:=0 to RbnImgList.count-1 do
  begin
   if FileExists(RbnImgPath + 'v' + IntToStr(vNo) + '\' + RbnImgFolder+'\' + IntToStr(i)+'.bmp') then
   begin
    //NEED TO CATCH BAD FILES THAT COULDN'T BE READ.
    CurrentPNG.LoadFromFile(RbnImgPath + 'v' + IntToStr(vNo) + '\' + RbnImgFolder+'\' + IntToStr(i)+'.png');
    //bitmap.LoadFromFile(RbnImgPath + 'v' + IntToStr(vNo) + '\' + RbnImgFolder+'\' + IntToStr(i)+'.bmp');
    bitmap.Assign(CurrentPNG);
    //ImageList.Add(Convert_PNG_To_bitmap(CurrentPNG), nil);
    ImageList.Add(bitmap, nil);
   end;
   //else //Fill any left with placeholders.
    //ImageList.Add(PlcHolderBmp, nil);
  end;
  bitmap.free;
  //CurrentPNG.free;
  PlcHolderBmp.free;
end;
```

As you can see, I've been trying to add the images as Bitmaps and PNGs. In the end though, they always need to be converted to Bitmaps in order to be added to the lists anyway.

Comment: The standard way to get masked imagelists is to explicitly add a [mask bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761389(v=vs.85).aspx). I used to do this with C, but it's a standard Win API approach.

Comment: Ok. I will try to find an example on how to do this.